# TypeError: Cannot read property 'recipeName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-dom

I've now gone through my code with a fine tooth comb and I just cannot seem to see where the "recipe" property is not defined.  I'm hoping some more experienced eyes would help me out and spot where I've made the mistake.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Ps. Please find my code below... it's the Recipe Box project from FreeCodeCamp and I followed the walk through from Dylan Israel from CodingTutorials360.  As far as I can tell my code is identical to his except for some changes to React-Bootstrap as stipulated by the Documentation.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Panel from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Panel'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'
import ButtonToolbar from 'react-bootstrap/lib/ButtonToolbar'
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Modal'
import FormGroup from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormGroup'
import ControlLabel from 'react-bootstrap/lib/ControlLabel'
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControl'
import PanelGroup from 'react-bootstrap/lib/PanelGroup'



class App extends Component {

  state = {
    showAdd: false,
    showEdit: false,
    currentIndex: 0,
    recipes: [

    ],
    newestRecipe: {recipeName:"", ingredients: []}
  }

  deleteRecipe(index){
    let recipes = this.state.recipes.slice();
    recipes.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('recipes', JSON.stringify(recipes));
    this.setState({recipes});
  }

  updateNewRecipe(value, ingredients){

    this.setState({newestRecipe:{recipeName: value, ingredients: ingredients}});
  }

  close = () => {
    if(this.state.showAdd){
      this.setState({showAdd: false});
    } else if(this.state.showEdit){
      this.setState({showEdit: false});
    }
  }

  open = (state, currentIndex) => {
    this.setState({[state]: true});
    this.setState({currentIndex});

  }

  saveNewRecipe = () => {
    let recipes = this.state.recipes.slice();
    recipes.push({recipeName: this.state.newestRecipe.recipeName, ingredients: this.state.newestRecipe.ingredients});
    localStorage.setItem('recipes', JSON.stringify(recipes));
    this.setState({ recipes });
    this.setState({newestRecipe: {recipeName: '', ingredients:[]}});
    this.close();
  }

  updateRecipeName(recipeName, currentIndex){
    let recipes = this.state.recipes.slice();

    recipes[currentIndex] = {recipeName: recipeName, ingredients: recipes[currentIndex].ingredients};
    this.setState({recipes});
    localStorage.setItem('recipes', JSON.stringify(recipes));
    this.close();
  }

  updateIngredients(ingredients, currentIndex){
    let recipes = this.state.recipes.slice();
    recipes[currentIndex] = {recipeName: recipes[currentIndex].recipeName, ingredients: ingredients};
    localStorage.setItem('recipes', JSON.stringify(recipes));
    this.setState({recipes});
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let recipes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipes")) || [];
    this.setState({recipes});
  }

  render() {
    const {recipes, newestRecipe, currentIndex} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App container" id="display-box">
        {recipes.length > 0 && (
          <div>
            <PanelGroup accordion id="recipe-list" defaultActiveKey="2">
            {recipes.map((recipe, index)=>(
              <Panel eventKey={index} key={index}>
                <Panel.Heading>
                  <Panel.Title toggle>{recipe.recipeName}</Panel.Title>
                </Panel.Heading>
                <Panel.Body collapsible>
                  <ol>
                    {recipe.ingredients.map((item)=>(
                      <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                    ))}
                  </ol>
                  <ButtonToolbar>
                    <Button bsStyle="danger" onClick={(event)=>this.deleteRecipe(index)}>Delete Recipe</Button>
                    <Button bsStyle="default" onClick={(event) => this.open("showEdit", index)}>Edit Recipe</Button>
                  </ButtonToolbar>
                </Panel.Body>
              </Panel>
              ))}
            </PanelGroup>
          </div>
        )}

        <Modal show={this.state.showEdit} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Edit Recipe</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText">
              <ControlLabel>Recipe Name</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                type="text"
                value={recipes[currentIndex].recipeName}
                placeholder="Enter Text" onChange={(event) => this.updateRecipeName(event.target.value, currentIndex)}
              />
            </FormGroup>

            <FormGroup controlId="formControlsTextarea">
              <ControlLabel>Ingredients</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl 
                componentClass="textarea"
                onChange={(event) => this.updateIngredients(event.target.value.split(","), currentIndex)}
                placeholder="Enter Ingredients [Seperate by Commas]"
                value={recipes[currentIndex].ingredients}>
              </FormControl>
            </FormGroup>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={(event) => this.saveNewRecipe()}>Save Changes</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>

        <Modal show={this.state.showAdd} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Add Recipe</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText">
              <ControlLabel>Recipe Name</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                type="text"
                value={newestRecipe.recipeName}
                placeholder="Enter Recipe Name"
                onChange={(event) => this.updateNewRecipe(event.target.value, newestRecipe.ingredients)}
              >
              </FormControl>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup controlId="formControlTextarea">
              <ControlLabel>Ingredients</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                type="textarea"
                placeholder="Enter Ingredients [Seperate by Commas]"
                onChange={(event) => this.updateNewRecipe(newestRecipe.recipeName, event.target.value.split(','))}
                value={newestRecipe.ingredients}
              >
              </FormControl>
            </FormGroup>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={(event) => {this.saveNewRecipe()}}>Save</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>

        <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={(event)=>this.open("showAdd", currentIndex)}>Add Recipe</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: So looks like there's around 6 places where the error could happen (i.e. where you're accessing the 'recipeName' property of an object which could potentially be undefined). Have you printed out the parent object in each of those cases to check it actually exists?

Comment: The error line number would be helpful (rather spot the error line out from your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing (twice) to the current recipe data when there is not a current recipe. That is because, although you are not showing the "modal", you are rendering it.

One possible solution is to render that modal only if you are editing something, you could do this replacing lines 110-139 with this:

```
{ this.state.showEdit &&
      <Modal show={this.state.showEdit} onHide={this.close}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Edit Recipe</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText">
            <ControlLabel>Recipe Name</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              value={recipes[currentIndex].recipeName}
              placeholder="Enter Text" onChange={(event) => this.updateRecipeName(event.target.value, currentIndex)}
            />
          </FormGroup>

          <FormGroup controlId="formControlsTextarea">
            <ControlLabel>Ingredients</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl 
              componentClass="textarea"
              onChange={(event) => this.updateIngredients(event.target.value.split(","), currentIndex)}
              placeholder="Enter Ingredients [Seperate by Commas]"
              value={recipes[currentIndex].ingredients}>
            </FormControl>
          </FormGroup>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={(event) => this.saveNewRecipe()}>Save Changes</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    }
```

Note that the only thing I did is to add the first and the last line of that block of code.

Comment: That did it!!  Thanks so much!!  So was it because I had 2 Modals rendered at the same time?

Comment: @BlackBat023 No, in this line `value={recipes[currentIndex].recipeName}`, when you initially run the app it is recipes[0], which is `undefined` (the array is empty), so you are trying to do `undefined.recipeName`, as the error says. With the lines that I added, all the JSX after `&&` and before `}` is not executed until `this.state.showEdit` is `true`, so you don't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you are not defining your initial state correctly, which may be the reason why you are getting an undefined error.

Usually, state is initially defined in the constructor function, and not as a separate object. When I tried to define the state like you did, I got an error on codepen.
Check out how they define state in this cheat sheet (under States): https://devhints.io/react.

I've gone through the same FreeCodeCamp react projects, and some of these can take a long time to figure out, but in the end it's really worth it. Hopefully this will help you find the error :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a constructor to define the state and bind your function saveNewRecipe

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  state = {
    showAdd: false,
    showEdit: false,
    currentIndex: 0,
    recipes: [

    ],
    newestRecipe: {recipeName:"", ingredients: []}
  };

  this.saveNewRecipe = this.saveNewRecipe.bind(this);
}
```